# Convergence of filters in top.

Tags: general-topology, filters

Let $X$ be any set equip with the dis. topology and $x\in X$. What filters $\mathscr{F}$ converge to $x$, written $\mathscr{F}\to x$?

---

A filter $\mathscr{F}$ is said to converge to $x$, written $\mathscr{F}\to x$, if $\mathscr{F}_x\subseteq\mathscr{F}$, where $\mathscr{F}_x$ is the nhbd filter of $x$.

Therefore, $\mathscr{F}\to x$, if,

$$\mathscr{A}:=\{A\subseteq X:\exists U\in\tau\text{ such that } x\in U\subseteq A\}\subseteq\mathscr{F}.$$

However, I don't see where to go from here. Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ is a non-empty set then for every point $x \in X$ there is the fixed filter $\mathcal{F}_x=\{A \subseteq X\mid x \in A\}$. It's clear that this is even a maximal (by inclusion) filter, i.e. an ultrafilter.

If $(X,\tau)$ is the discrete space and $\mathcal{F}$ is a (proper) filter on $X$:

$$\forall x: (\mathcal{F} \to x \iff \mathcal{F}=\mathcal{F}_x)$$

Left to right: $\{x\}$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ in $(X,\tau)$ so if $\mathcal{F}$ converges to $x$, $\{x\}$ must be an element of $\mathcal{F}$. But then by the filter axioms all $A \in \mathcal{F}_x$, so all $A$ with $\{x\} \subseteq A$, are also in $\mathcal{F}$, hence $\mathcal{F}_x \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ and if $A \in \mathcal{F}$ it must intersect $\{x\}$ so that $x \in A$ and so $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_x$ too. Hence $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{F}_x$.

Right to left is trivial, as $\mathcal{F}_x$ is exactly the neighbourhood filter of $x$ in $(X,\tau)$.

So precisely the fixed filters converge, and no others.

Comment: Thanks! However, did you mean to write $\mathscr{F}_x = \{A\subseteq X: x\in A\}$ instead of $\mathscr{F}_x = \{A\subseteq X: x\in X\}$? Also, could you write this for the trivial topology?

Comment: @D.Math for the trivial topology every filter converges to every point of $X$. This is easy to see.